# How to track any moving object with a non static camera? [Opencv]

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to track **any moving** object with a non-static camera and also get the contours of that object. Can someone give me some suggestions how I can achieve that goal?

I tought about substracting the background but that will only work for satic cameras.

Comment: You can try using SURF, like in this tutorial: http://morf.lv/modules.php?name=tutorials&lasit=2

Answer (score 4):

Background subtraction is not an option in non-static camera. Subtraction of first frame with the warped Homography output of the second frame might work in some cases, but the occurrence of error will be high.

The best bet is the use of Feature Detector algorithms like FAST, ORB, SURF, SIFT, BRISK etc. If performance is an issue, FAST or ORB can be the best option. These FD algorithms track and map the "stable points" present in the images. Corners, for example, can be termed as a "stable point" as translation, scaling, skewing, rotating etc wont change their properties.

Code to track the "stable points"/ keypoints on the 2nd frame with that of the 1st frame are widely available on net.

Each of the above mentioned algorithm have their own pros and cons. Select an algorithm depending on your needs. It is to be noted that thought SIFT/SURF is the best in terms of accuracy, they are patent encumbered.

Answer (score 2):

ANY moving object, or any kind of object but only a known number of known/detected objects at a time?

You could try to estimate the camera movement to identify the background. 
Optical flow could be a hint there, depending on how the camera moves, the sectors of the image would move the pixels in special directions.
[image]
There exist other methods to identify camera movement, maybe search for "camera self calibration" techniques.

Once you know camera movement, you can try to reconstruct parts of the scene in 3D, knowing which objects moved. Maybe there exist other methods to extract the background without 3D reconstruction (would be a bit overkill and maybe not fast/good enough for your needs).

I remember a paper of foreground extraction, where small camera displacements were handled. Have a look at http://www2.ulg.ac.be/telecom/publi/publications/barnich/Barnich2011ViBe/index.html

For general object tracking (if you know what your interesting objects are or if you extracted them), I would suggest a particle filter with color histogram to represent the tracked object and compute the likelihood. Have a look at: http://www.irisa.fr/vista/Papers/2002/perez_hue_eccv02.pdf
Or a feature tracking with SIFT/SURF features.

The hard thing is to decide what is foreground and what is background for a moving (not just rotating) camera. If that camera motion is limited, it might be easier.